# jQuery variable value is not getting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a, A tag in my PHP page like this

```
<a class='likelink' href='javascript:void(0)'>amblex</a>
```

When I click this link, the following jQuery will run.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
          $('.likelink').click(function() {
                $("#myDiv").load("givedocroots.php?link=$(this).value()");
          });
    });
</script>
```

But the `$(this).value()` inside the jQuery is not working, means `link` variable is not getting the A tag value `amblex`.

What change do I need to do to get the `givedocroots.php?link=$(this).value()` working properly?

Comment: For start, you obviously shouldn't have a piece of code enclosed in double quotes. Kinda makes no sense, right?

Comment: And secondly, `a` elements don’t have a “value”. What you are looking for is the _text_ content of the `a` element.

Comment: Also it is not value() but val() http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get value from anchor. You want to get its text instead.

Then you need to use `+` to concatenate your value in javascript:

```
$("#myDiv").load("givedocroots.php?link=" + $(this).text());
```

Comment: This worked fine dude :). Thankyou very much for quick response Eli.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
$(function() {
      $('.likelink').click(function() {
            var link = $(this).text();
            $("#myDiv").load("givedocroots.php?link="+link);
      });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
$("#myDiv").load("givedocroots.php?link=" + $(this).text());
```

Comment: This worked fine Claudio. Thankyou very much for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

That's because:

1. it's `.val()`, not `.value()`;
2. it shouldn't be inside a quoted string.
3. A link won't have a *value*, `.val()` applies to form fields. You can get the text contained within a tag with `.text()` if you need just the plain text or `.html()` if you need the text with HTML tags.

If you change it to:

```
$("#myDiv").load("givedocroots.php?link=" + $(this).text());
```

it should work just fine.

Comment: It's not `.val()` either, in this case..

Comment: Yeah, fixed that, it was some hasty reading on my part.